# How do I submit an iphone app that utilizes a pathmapp sdk to the app store?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am using pathmapp sdk in my app. When i upload app to app store that says, "Invalid Bundle Structure - the binary file 'NoNotesVoice.app/pathmapp' is not permitted. Your app may contain only one executable file". Does anyone please know the solution to this problem?

Comment: Provide some extra information please

Comment: check your Project Folder (maybe Build was saved to project folder). Save build to an empty "Staging" folder..

Comment: This can be caused, also.. by trying to post an application in debug mode.  Verify in your iOS deploy profile that the app is set to be in release mode. Do a clean-all before deploying your application

Comment: My guess is that you have pathmapp contains a executable file that you have added to your project.